# Button with mysql query in action

Tags: mysql, button, dropdown

I created a dropdown list with 6 options.

After select an option and clicking the submit button, the selected value should be inserted into the mysql database. This is code:

```
<form name="name" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<select id="broj" name="name">                      
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="2">Option 1</option>
  <option value="3">Option 2</option>
  <option value="4">Option 3</option>
  <option value="5">Option 4</option>
  <option value="6">Option 5</option>
  <option value="7">Option 6</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if($_GET){
   $result= $_GET['name'];
  }
?>
// 
After this follows the code that inserts the $result into the mysql database
```

I have two problems with this code:

1. As soon as the page is opened (before clicking the button) , the value 0 is inserted into the database (value of "Select" option)
2. After refreshing page, the selected value is re-insert into the database

How to make the selected option inserted into the database only when the submit button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change your form method to POST instead of GET. And check for post before insert into database

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        // Code insert into database here
    }
```

In your code I see

```
    action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] with form method GET will contain your submit parameter and that may cause some strange problems. I think there may be no problem if you let action="", your form still submit data to current page

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` does not pass through the GET values; you might be thinking of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 0):

**First visit to the page inserts a 0-value row:**

The relevant code for this is excluded from your question, but you should always check that your $_GET (or $_POST, or $_REQUEST, or $_SESSION, etc) array has at least one value (eg `if (count($_GET))`) before inserting. However, I would suggest that you use the POST method rather than GET. It's one tiny layer of obfuscation for someone trying to force data into your DB, and it makes it a lot harder for accidents/mistyped URLs to insert random data.

**Resubmitted data:**

This has a few ways to work around it. Most people simply set the `POST` method for their forms, rather than GET (there are some standards that say you should use POST, but I won't get into that). If the user attempts to refresh a page that a form POSTed to, most modern browsers will pop up a confirmation dialogue box before resubmitting the form data.

Another common technique is to [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) from the form's target page once the data has been inserted into the database. That way the user can't refresh the page. In other words, you would have a blank form response page that simply does the DB insert and then redirects to a page with a "thank you for submitting the form" text, or whatever you want to display after the form is submitted. The user's browser never sits on the URL/page that does the actual DB insert.

You could also do a little validation before doing the insert. If you don't want to query your DB before inserting (or apply a DB-level constraint, like a unique index on the table), you could have each form submit a one-use token with each request. If a form gets submitted with that token a second time, then you know it was a resubmit. A simple example of this might be to add a captcha to your form.